# Collision logic error

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am trying to make a Pong game and I got stuck on the collision detection. The problem is coming from the method below. I can't figure out my logic error. Note: player1 and Circle are both objects of a rectangle that i am using to be able to make them interact with each other.
Thank you.

```
public void moveBall(){
    ball.x += speed;

    //checks if the ball intersects with the paddle Player 1 
    if (ball.intersects(player2) && ball.getY() >= player2.getY() && ball.getY() <= player2.getY() + 70){
        speed *= (-1);
    }


}
```

Comment: What does your `intersects()` method do?

Comment: I'm guessing it's a copy/paste error, but your comment says you're checking for Player 1 intersection and the code looks like you're checking Player 2.

Comment: @azurefrog It appears that `ball` might be a Rectangle, kind of hard to tell in this case without the rest of the code/explanation

Comment: On a side note, don't do `speed *= (-1);`. Use `speed = -speed;` instead.

Comment: @phflack It might be, but I'd rather ask the OP to include more information  than spend time guessing.

Comment: Also, what is `speed`?  Is it just the speed, and somewhere else you have a direction of which way the ball is going?  If you just negate the speed, it will bounce off the wall the same direction it came, instead of bouncing off the wall with normal physics

Comment: Speed is the interval that the X changes.

Comment: And also, I still haven't done the other player's collision detection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem may be that as soon as the ball touches the player, speed is multiplied by -1 then, the ball moves However, the ball doesn't move far enough so, the collision may be registered again causing speed to be multiplied by -1 again. To solve this just move the ball after changing the value of 'speed'

Solution:

```
public void moveBall(){
ball.x += speed;

//checks if the ball intersects with the paddle Player 1 
if (ball.intersects(player2) ){
    speed *= (-1);
   ball.x += 3*speed;
}
```

}

Also, you don't need the line `ball.getY() >= player2.getY() && ball.getY() <= player2.y` as the `Rectangle.intersects` method also checks if the y coordinates match.

Hope this helped.

Comment: I tried what you said above but it still doesn't work. For some reason, the ball just gets deflected once it hits the same X axis but not the Y.

Comment: Just changed some variable names and found my problem. Thanks!